# SwiftUI linear gauge

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader

**UPDATE**

I was able to get something closer to what I'm trying to achieve. Still needs work. I attempted to use a rounded rectangle for the mask but doesn't look good. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```swift
GeometryReader { geometry in
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7.5, style: .circular)
        .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.green, Color.yellow, Color.orange, Color.red, Color.purple]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top))
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .bottomLeading)
        .overlay(Color.black.opacity(0.35).cornerRadius(7.5))
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7.5, style: .circular)
        .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.green, Color.yellow, Color.orange, Color.red, Color.purple]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top))
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .bottomLeading)
        .mask(
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Rectangle()
                    // Adjust value 1 to needs
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height:geometry.size.height * (CGFloat(1) / CGFloat(11)), alignment: .bottom)
            })
}
.frame(width: 15, height: .infinity)
.padding(.all, 10)
```

**Older**

I'm attempting to create a simple gauge like the linear gauge in watchOS. The trouble I'm having is figuring out the proper way to overlay the current value. The outcome I'd like to see is below. I'm sure there's a better way.

Outcome

[image]

Mine look absolutely terrible

[image]

```swift
ZStack {
    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.green, Color.yellow, Color.orange, Color.red, Color.purple]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)
    GeometryReader { metrics in
        Circle()
            .stroke(Color.white,lineWidth: 2)
            .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: metrics.size.height)
            .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
            .position(x: metrics.size.width / 2 ,y: metrics.size.height * (CGFloat(10) / CGFloat(11)))
    }
}
.cornerRadius(7.5)
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 15)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've solved my solution. I managed to create the same view by making a custom `ProgressView` style.

[image]

Comment: where found the code?

Comment: You can actually now just use the gauge style progress view in SwiftUI for iOS not just watchOS.